# Twitter status update from C app

Tags: api, winapi, post, twitter

Inspired by [Scripting Twitter with cURL](http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2007/03/18/scripting-twitter-with-curl/), I'm trying to make a command line app in C, used to update my Twitter status.

I'm not really sure how curl works in this case... I guess by appending the newly created status to the XML.

My question is: how to implement POST in C (libcurl is not used)? Maybe just by using networking functions from Win32 API?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter no longer supports Basic Authentication with a username/password. You will have to use OAuth. There are a number of [OAuth libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries) available that might fit your need.